# How to install openshift container platform enterprise as all-in-one installation

Tags: openshift, redhat, openshift-enterprise

I am having RHEL7 OS VM of 16GB RAM and 4core CPU. I wanted to install openshift container platform 4.6.3 version as a all-in-one installation as I don't wanted to use codeready container platform for this purpose is there any way how I can install openshift 4x version as  all-in-one installation.

Answer (score 1):

No, installing OpenShift Container Platform 4.6 on this particular VM is not possible for multiple reasons:

- In any case, the Control Plane requires Red Hat CoreOS as its Operating System.
- The smallest possible OCP cluster is a [Three-Node OpenShift Compact Cluster](https://www.openshift.com/blog/delivering-a-three-node-architecture-for-edge-deployments), where Control Plane nodes are also used to schedule workload. A single-node cluster installation does not exist at this time (apart from CodeReady Containers, which you do not want to use).
- Even with the small cluster above, you are looking at at least 3x 24GB of RAM as the minimum requirement. VMs with less RAM might work, but the cluster will likely be unstable.

With limited resources, the only way to run OpenShift 4 is to use [CodeReady Containers](https://developers.redhat.com/products/codeready-containers/overview).

Comment: but i found this resource which tells we can deploy as all-in-one https://www.openshift.com/blog/revamped-openshift-all-in-one-aio-for-labs-and-fun, so is it possible to deploy openshift using this resource

Comment: The blog post notes more CPU resources being necessary and this is also using CoreOS, so not what you specified in your original question.